# Prevent page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working to discover all possible functions on a page and so am simulating a click / mouseover on all elements using this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var elements = $("body").find("*");
 setTimeout(function () { 
    elements.each(function(e){
       elements[e].click();
 }, 400)
});
```

I can get it to work if I do this, but obviously that leaves out a lot of items.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var elements = $("body").find("*");


setTimeout(function () { 
    elements.each(function(e){
        if (elements[e].localName == "a" | elements[e].localName == "span"  | elements[e].localName == "li" | elements[e].localName == "i"){
                console.log(elements[e]);
        }
        if (elements[e].localName != "a" && elements[e].localName != "span"  && elements[e].localName != "li" && elements[e].localName != "i"){
            if (!elements[e].href){


                elements[e].click();
            }
        }
    })
}, 400)

});
```

I tried functions like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'false';
}
// or this
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

But those are ignored by firefox and I end up at either a login page, or it tries submitting a form, or another link off the navigation. I can't just exclude all the elements from the search, what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

It must be:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Nope, that is ignored as described in post.

Comment: In your post you had a typo this is the right way to use it